# Настройка Retrofit (POST запрос, Body)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, swagger

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки POST запроса, работаю со Swagger Web Api. Не могу понять, какие данные ждёт сервер и как их правильно обернуть (так как посылаю правильные данные, а получаю ответ что они некорректны).

Сервер ждёт следующие данные: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я выполняю следующий код:

```
   User mUser = new User("Android","qwerty");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObj.put("Login", mUser.getLogin());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonObj.put("Password", mUser.getPassword());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Call<TokenResponse> mTokenResponseCall = service.getData(jsonObj);

            mTokenResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
                    int mStatusCode = response.code();

                    TokenResponse mTokenResponse = response.body();

                    Log.d("LoginActivity","onResponse " + mStatusCode);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("LoginActivity","onFailure" + t);
                }
            });
```

А Retrofit выглядит, так:

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@POST("Api/Account/Login")
Call<TokenResponse> getData(@Body JSONObject Obj);
```

**P.S.** 
На сервер отправляется следующая строчка 
{"nameValuePairs":{"Login":"Android","Password":"qwerty"}}

Comment: Подключите логирование и посмотрите, что именно уходит на сервер. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Comment: А ответ от сервера есть? Что в OnResponse в response.errorBody() ?

Comment: @hardsky Ответ с сервера есть. Он возвращает код 200 и присылает данные "Такой пользователь не найден". В errorBody()=null

Comment: @EgorChetvernin, это смахивает на то, что ретрофит у вас правильно настроен и работает, а сервис не находит пользователя с таким логином/паролем и присылает вам об этом сообщение.

Comment: @hardsky но в Swagger я ввожу те же данные, и он находит этого пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже писал выше, на сервер отправляется следующая строчка {"nameValuePairs":{"Login":"Android","Password":"qwerty"}}.

А сервер ожидает: {"Login":"Android","Password":"qwerty"}

Для этого используйте JsonObject из библиотеки com.google.gson.*.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Пост сделать так

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@POST("Api/Account/Login")
    Call<Void> getData(
            @Field("login") String login,
            @Field("password") String password);
```

Второе - json не понимает больших букв. Если сервер ждёт `Login/Password`, а приходит `login/password`, то может быть ошибка. Попробуйте, чтобы сервер тоже ждал login/password (с маленькой буквы).

Comment: к сожалению, в данном случае приходит код 500. Дело в том, swagger ждёт Body и код 200 приходит только при Body. C Field не получается.